# Julia pipeline and run

Tags: julia

How do I direct `stdout` to a file in the following two ways using `run`:

```
echo "col1 col2" > hi.csv
echo "col1 col2" >> hi.csv
```

run(pipeline(`echo "col1 col2"`, stdout="hi.csv"))

^ trouble formatting that

is the answer to the first, but what about the second?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`` run(pipeline(`echo "col1 col2"`, stdout="hi.csv", append=true)) ``

Comment: Thanks. To editorialize, I wish they would somehow let `run()` take a bash command with ">>" , ">", "|" etc. as usual...

Comment: Using those special characters in command objects was just deprecated so Julia can eventually implement that.  https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/21809

Comment: Yes, in 0.7/1.0 this will just work. So your wish will be granted :)